# Validate jsonschema with defaults where input can be both object and string

Tags: python, yaml, jsonschema

I am making use of snakemake [validate](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/snakemake/utils.html) which is heavily based on [jsonschema](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) to validate my (yaml) configuration. Users have to choose an option, and can specify more detailed parameters if they want, otherwise it should default to the defaults in the config.yaml.

```
# problem that bwa is string, does not default
aligner:
  bwa

# defaults nicely for align
aligner:
  hisat2:
    index: 'parameters'

# works!
aligner:
  salmon:
    index: 'parameters1'
    align: 'parameters2'
```

My config.yaml now looks like this:

```
  aligner:
    description: which aligner to use
    properties:
      bwa:
        properties:
          index:
            default: 'def_param'
          align:
            default: 'def_param'
      hisat2:
        properties:
          index:
            default: 'def_param'
          align:
            default: 'def_param'
      salmon:
        properties:
          index:
            default: 'def_param'
          align:
            default: 'def_param'
    minProperties: 1
    additionalProperties: false
    default:
      bwa:
        index: -a bwtsw
        align: ''
```

How do I make it so that it also defaults for the case that people only specify an aligner?

Comment: `...the case that people only specify an aligner?` Could you explain what you mean by this specifically please? I cannot understand. Maybe provide an example?

Comment: @Relequestual: I mean the first out of the three examples in the config.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your examples, it looks like the library you're using takes defaults including objects. As such, to set the default of the object `bwa`, you would need to define the default at the same level as its properties, like this...

```
aligner:
  description: which aligner to use
  properties:
    bwa:
      properties:
        index:
          default: 'def_param'
        align:
          default: 'def_param'
      default:
        index: 'def_param'
        align: 'def_param'
```

I think you no longer want to then define the default for the individual properties of the object.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to test this works as you expect.

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'. I'm about to head home, I'll make a small example later today.

Comment: It could be that in your data, `bwa` is a string and not an empty object.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure that's the case.

Comment: I figured it out thanks to your help. I misunderstood how snakemake validates the configuration under the hood. I added a simple check that if config['aligner'] is a string, then convert it to a dictionary. That, in combination with your config, solved it. Thanks!